# cluster analysis in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, random-forest

This is (a piece of) my data frame

```
time_step       V1      V2      V3      V4      V5
1               120.8   139.5   NA      124.9   148
2               NA      139.3   NA      127.5   156.1
3               120.6   139.5   131.9   130.7   159.6
4               NA      139     133.9   135     169.5
5               NA      138.3   138.7   137.4   169.1
6               120     138.9   137     139.8   168.4
7               NA      139.5   135.2   142.1   172.9
8               NA      137.1   135.9   143     176.3
```

Each column is a curve with values eventually missing inbetween.

So I want to use random forest to basically find out how many categories of curves I have to assume.

To do this, I thought I would have to fitt each of these curves first using GAMMS with bam() command of R package 'mgcv'
and then use cluster analysis to find out the categories.
But maybe the curve fitting is not important.

Can anybody help and do you think this might work?

This is a photo of how I am expecting the data to look like, though I classified the curves myself into three categories:
[Categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aEuX.png)

With random forest, I would like to statistically find out a categorization and whether it fits to my impressionistic one or whether empirically it would be better to assume n categories.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you want to achieve. Linear model and randomForest are two different models. You can supply all data to randomforest - not necessary to do feature selection.

Answer (score 1):

Random forests are not really used for unsupervised learning, that is "finding out the number of categories", other algorithms are better suited for this task, such as clustering. Once you have the number of categories and their labels you can use RF to predict new cases.

Comment: What I actually wanted to do is a cluster analysis not random forest. I got confused there. Do you think it is possible and usefull here?

Comment: Cluster analysis is always an option, although you should edit your question and provide more information about your data and these "curves" you mentioned, where do they come from? why do you think there are curves? is this time series data? other options may be more appropriate based on domain  knowledge.

Comment: it is time series data of pitch values of spoken language. The data is normalized over time; for every syllable a fixed number of values have been taken. So the pitch data correlates to what impressionistically can be classified into 3 categories but I would like to kind of go more exploratory with the cluster analysis.

Comment: In that case, k-means or GMM's (Gaussian Mixture Models) are popular clustering algorithms that work well out of the box.